# cdt eclipse - force include directory to be recognized as source

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I would like my Eclipse to recognize the Include directory as if it would be one of source directories, so I can make use of functionality like " New -> New Header File".
Currently I cannot do that because of error "*..Include is not a source folder*":

Is there any way to force **Include directory** to be treated as Source directory within eclipse?

I do have that directory added to **Source Location**, however I think because its recognized as Include directory eclipse refuses to treat it as source directory

Comment: Did you resolve this eventually?

Comment: @einpoklum sort of.. I think the only thing I did  was changing build system to use mingw instead of msvc, after that I am almost sure that it was fixed. However I am not sure about this.